# Node.js SQLite 3 Return Promise

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sqlite

I am somewhat new to node.js and I figured out how to use it with SQLite but I would like to make wrapper functions so I don't have to have SQL statements all over my code. This code prints out the result of the query:

```
 Users.find_by_id = function(id){
  db.all("SELECT * from users WHERE id=" + id, function(err, row){
    console.log(row);
  });
};
```

I know that node.js is asynchronous so I can't return the values themselves but I was wondering if it was possible to return a promise with the values in question.

Comment: Which version you are using? If you are using node 5, take a look at this package https://github.com/kriasoft/node-sqlite

Comment: It says my version is v0.10.37. Is this very out of date/worth an update?

Comment: If you want to use promises there are a lot of packages you can use. I like [Q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q). You can also take a callback function as a parameter and call that when you're done, passing the data to the function.

Comment: Well if are just learning you might just change to latest node version, so you can have some of es6 cool stuff

Comment: I honestly can't make heads or tails of how that package is used.

Comment: @rgvassar I ended up implementing this using Q. Thanks!

Comment: @user5505266 I went ahead and made it an answer, so you can mark this as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use promises there are a lot of packages you can use. I like Q. Without promises you can take a callback function as a parameter and call that when you're done, passing the data to the function.